# What's the name of this card game (using a standard deck but each suit has abilities)?

Tags: identify-this-game

So, I believe I read about this roughly two years ago.

Someone created a ruleset to play with a standard deck of cards. I think every suit represented a specific class and had certain abilities. The immediate feedback was very positive.

If I'm not mistaken, there was also a Kickstarter (or similar opportunity) to purchase a deck with custom art, tailored to the ruleset. But, the game's perfectly playable with regular playing cards.

I tried googling, asking Bard, and focusing on BGG, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: @Zibelas that looks like an amazing candidate and checks all the boxes, but I don't think it was cooperative. It's quite possible that every suit had a similar ability, like healing, attacking, etc. Sorry I don't have more details.

Comment: There are similarities in your description with "Chronicle" by Seiji Kanai, but not all details fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First game that came to my mind is [Regicide](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/307002/regicide).

- It came out 2020
- It is on [Kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/badgersfrommars/regicide?lang=de) with special art but
- it can be played by a normal deck of cards
- Each card suit has a special ability
- It can be played solo or with up to 4 players (boardgamearena has it implemented)